# Script Error occur in VS 2012 Help Viewer

Tags: visual-studio, documentation

I am using Sandcastle Help file builder (1.9.4.0), Sandcastle (2.7.0.0) and .NET Framework 4.0 assemblies to generate the Class reference for Visual Studio.

I have used Framework version is .NET 4.0.30319 and Help File Format is MSHelpViewer and Presentation Style is vs2005 in Sandcastle Help file builder. It is working fine in VS 2010 (Help viewer 1.1). It shows Script error in VS 2012 (Help Viewer 2.0).
Shall I need to change any settings to solve this issue? 
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

I randomly get this error. There's a lot of stuff online that requires you to mess with the registry and such. A much easier solution I found somewhere is to go to select Manage Content icon, and then make some change to the Help contents that you have selected, for example Add in some help topic that is currently not in, or Remove some topic. Then click Update, and its usually fine after that!